# Rearrange Row data based on cells values automatically

Tags: excel, vba

Sheet1 Have 90 columns and 288 rows. Some cells of each row have value and some are blank (containing formula). I want to rearrange each row data in Sheet2 as value contain cells come to left and blank goes to right. I don’t want to remove the blank cells so, if a row doesn’t have any data will not got removed. Row order is very important in my case. 
Sheet1 got updated each 5 minutes, if there is any possibility to update Sheet2 each 5 minute that will be really great.
Example: 
 Sheet1
[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk18X.png)

Sheet2[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF68G.png)

NB: My VBA or Macro knowledge is very basic. If I’m not asking too much, explanation to apply the solutions will be great.
Using office 365 latest version

Comment: Your 'VBA or macro knowledge' does not only appears to be 'very basic'; in fact, it appears non-existent.

Comment: Well, that's right. Any suggestion or direction will be highly appreciated. Anyway I can improve my question?

Comment: I Voted-To-Close your question because you are asking for code and not supplying any. This is not a place to get free code that you are too lazy or incapable to write. To improve your question: **WRITE CODE AND INCLUDE IT IN YOUR QUESTION ALONG WITH A DESCRIPTION OF ANY ERROR OR PROBLEM** ([ask]).

Comment: Got it and really sorry to waste yours time. I'm incapable but not lazy. I have tried to search last few days here and google. All the suggestions are based on column not based on rows. Anyway thanks and sorry again.

Comment: Sort each row, one at a time, from left to right.  Record a macro while you do that; then clean up the macro.

Comment: @ Ron.   Thanks for your suggestion. Will work on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a hard time finding a place to start, you could try this [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro for Sheet1.

```
Option Explicit

Private dALL As Double

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.Sum(Target.Parent.UsedRange.Cells) <> dALL Then
        dALL = Application.Sum(Target.Parent.UsedRange.Cells)
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        'suspend events so nothing on Sheet2 gets triggered
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim a As Long, i As Long, j As Long, aVALs As Variant
        aVALs = Target.Parent.UsedRange.Cells.Value2
        For i = LBound(aVALs, 1) To UBound(aVALs, 1)
            For j = LBound(aVALs, 2) To UBound(aVALs, 2) - 1
                If Not CBool(Len(aVALs(i, j))) Then
                    For a = j + 1 To UBound(aVALs, 2)
                        If CBool(Len(aVALs(i, a))) Then
                            aVALs(i, j) = aVALs(i, a)
                            aVALs(i, a) = vbNullString
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next a
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
            .UsedRange.Clear
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(aVALs, 1), UBound(aVALs, 2)) = aVALs
        End With
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your continuous support. For sure I will start here and will update. Thanks again.